# Получить все формы глагол. NLTK

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

Нужно получить все формы глагола.

Примеры:

write->writing, wrote

play->played, playing,

Comment: А если серьёзно - вот поделились вы с нами своей нуждой. А кодом не поделились? Или вы нам задание даёте? Так фриланс-биржа на другом сайте.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753021/using-nltk-and-wordnet-how-do-i-convert-simple-tense-verb-into-its-present-pas